# Why won't my wikipedia opensearch ajax request return successfully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have tried in many different ways but I cannot get the success block to execute and I keep having the ajax request return as an error though the url is correct. My error says "undefined". Do you have any ideas of something else I could try?
Thank you for your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var searchTerm = $("#searchterm").val();
    var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" +
      searchTerm + "&format=json";

    $.ajax({
      url: proxy + url,

      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      },

      error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(url);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you really have a newline between `api.php?` and `action=...`? That's a JavaScript syntax error

Comment: Also, what does the error say?

Comment: I do not. That was just a formatting error on my part while submitting my (very first) question to Stackoverflow. Thank you for bringing that to my attention however!

Comment: The error simply says "undefined"

Comment: I just updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Seems to work for me. Check your browsers *Network* console.

Comment: Another thing you'll probably want to do is prevent the form from submitting via its usual method. You can do so by returning `false` in the submit handler function (after you make your AJAX call)

Comment: Hmm! Could you please show me what that would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your submit event handler add:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Because, by default, your form is cancelling your code and executing the submit event of your form.

Hope this helps you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchTerm = $("#searchterm").val();
    var proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" +
      searchTerm + "&format=json";

    $.ajax({
      url: proxy + url,

      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("ok");
      },

      error: function(request, status, error) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(url);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input id="searchterm" type="text" />
  <button id="btnSend" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```